# Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I want to make updates on an article and I need to track the lastmodified date. I get the above error conversion of a datetime2 data type to datetime data type.

Below is the code for my articlesController

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        EditArticlesVM model = new EditArticlesVM();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(EditArticlesVM model)
    {
        try
        {
            article objArticle = new article
            {
                articleID = model.articleID,
                articleTitle = model.articleTitle,
                articleContent = model.articleContent,
                lastmodified = DateTime.Now
            };
            objBs.articleBs.Update(objArticle);
            TempData["Msg"] = "Article Updated Successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Entity:'{0}' Property: '{1}' Error: '{2}'",
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                    validationError.PropertyName,
                    validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
            //throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed saving data: '{0}'", sb.ToString()), dbEx);

            TempData["Msg"] = sb.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code of `article` model ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not going to show the code of the `Article` model.This is my generic answer just for the time being.

You have to ensure that Start is greater than or equal to `SqlDateTime.MinValue (January 1, 1753)`.If you not set the default date then by default it takes as `DateTime.MinValue (January 1, 0001)`.

So SQL `datetime` data type cannot handle that value.That is why it shows above error.You have 2 solutions.One is, set a default date to the `datetime` properties on your `Article` model.second option is, change the SQL data type as `datetime2`.

Comment: I think OP have to define datetime nullable `DateTime?`

Comment: any feedback for this ?

Comment: Until OP not shows model `article` we can't get actual issue, you are right in the answer, which conclude *why this exception occurred*